# local vs remote image file path

Tags: rendering, blend-files, path, file-browser

I'm trying to upload my .blend file onto a render farm for rendering.

The images referenced by the image nodes are on the remote server, however they have a different path structure than I have on my local machine.

I've tried to edit the path of the image nodes before submitting to the farm, however, since that path does not exist locally blender doesn't let me save that path.

Is there a best practice for connecting image data when running on a remote farm vs working locally?

Perhaps a way to set environment variables depending on the local?

Comment: I believe the best way is to pack the .blend file, this way all your images will be included in the file.

Comment: Unfortunately that creates a very large file which, in the case of images being used in the composite, doesn't actually point to the images.  They go into a subdirectory which is then not referenced by the image node.